# Show that T is compact if $T^*T$ is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T: H\to H$ be a bounded linear operator. $T^*$ is the Hilbert adjoint operator. Show that $T$ is compact if $T^*T$ is compact.

I am stuck with this proof. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\lVert T(x) - T(y)\rVert^2 = \langle x-y, T^\ast T (x-y)\rangle$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\{ x_n \}_n $ be a sequence, bounded say by $M>0$. If $T^*T$ is compact, there exist a subsequence $\{ T^*T(x_{n_k})\}_k$ that converges and hence is Cauchy. Let $k<k' \in \mathbb{N}$, then 
\begin{align*}
\|T(x_{n_k}) - T(x_{n_{k'}}) \|^2 & =\| T(x_{n_k}-x_{n_{k'}}) \|^2 \\
& = \langle T(x_{n_k}-x_{n_{k'}}), T(x_{n_k}-x_{n_{k'}}) \rangle \\
& =\langle x_{n_k}-x_{n_{k'}}, T^*T(x_{n_k}-x_{n_{k'}}) \rangle \\
& \leq \| x_{n_k}-x_{n_{k'}}\| \|T^*T(x_{n_k}-x_{n_{k'}}) \| \\
& \leq 2M \| T^*T(x_{n_k})-T^*T(x_{n_{k'}}) \| \underset{k,k'\to \infty }{\longrightarrow} 0,
\end{align*} 
Therefore the sequence $\{ T(x_{n_k})\}_k$ is Cauchy and thus convergent. Since the image under $T$ of any bounded sequence admits a convergent subsequence, indeed $T$ is a compact operator.